# ruby on rails condition on a method - ruby on rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

i'm having a small problem. on the url i'm having this link
localhost:3000/reviews/displays/1 and on my method i'm having this

> @reviews = Review.find(:all, :conditions => { :events_ID =>
>   params[:id]})

there is a field on the reviews table called events_ID and i'm storing the id of the events. When i clicked on an event which has reviews it shows me that the event doesn't have any reviews in other words that @reviews is null. did i made any mistake on the condition?

[image]

[image]
Thank you
George

Comment: This looks correct. What happens when you try it from the rails console? Does the column on the table have that exact capitalization, and the underscore?

Comment: Are you sure the column is not called event_id?

Comment: yes because when you try to create a review is working fine and the events_ID is correct

Comment: Does the query look correct as well, and does the data look correct in your db? This looks fine based on your code.

Comment: Quick Security Tip: since you are using params[:id], make sure your model is protected against mass-assignment.

Comment: if i go to the index page of the reviews it's cites the id 1 to the events which exist. if i use the show page its fine. but when i use the display page it shows that there are not any data for this event

Comment: Are your sure your routes correctly set your "id" parameter ? Just display `params[:id]`, it could be `nil`

Comment: `id` is probably an integer and params[:id] is a string. Some databases get confused by that. Try `:events_ID => params[:id].to_i`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you have an Event model and a Review model.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, :foreign_key => :events_ID
end
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => :events_ID
end
```

Then instead of looking up reviews by event_ID, you use the association:

```
@event = Event.find params[:id]
@reviews = event.reviews
```

If that doesn't work, then we may need to know more about your schema.